# SIM800 doesn't give GSM location

Tags: microcontroller, gsm, sim, gprs

I have problem to get exact GSM location using SIM800L. I have followed instructions in the manual. But my module just gived me latitude = 0 and longitude = 0. This is what I do with my serial terminal.

```
AT+CGATT=1

OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"

OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","RCMNET"

OK
AT+SAPBR=1,1

OK
AT+SAPBR=2,1

+SAPBR: 1,1,"10.230.128.34"

OK
AT+CIPGSMLOC=1,1

+CIPGSMLOC: 0,0.000000,0.000000,2020/02/06,03:45:03

OK
```

I have used another way to solve this problem. This is my another step to get GSM location.

```
AT+CLBSCFG=0,1

+CLBSCFG: 0,1,""

OK
AT+CLBSCFG=0,2

+CLBSCFG: 0,2,0

OK
AT+CLBS=1,1

+CLBS: 2

OK
```

With "AT+CLBS=1,1", I still cannot access my SIM800 to get GSM location. This command always give me time out command without any solution.

Why is this happening? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that your network supports it?

Comment: I'm not sure.. Because in my country, when i check my phone at 2G connection, It's always in EDGE mode..

Comment: I have the same issue with the command AT+CLBS=1,1 it always return +CLBS: 2 (time out)

Answer (score 2):

AT+CIPGSMLOC is using google servers to identify nearest GSM tower. That was discontinued few months ago.

You can use triangulation using SIMCOM servers by upgrading to latest firmware 1418B05SIM800L24 and using AT+CLBS=1,1

Comment: Does it mean that the location can only be obtained via GPRS? I was hoping that the phone would get the location via triangulation between three closest towers. Is there such a functionality in SIM800?